# java - how to check a method on every method

Tags: java

```
public class Test
{
    private static boolean enable = true;

    public static boolean isEnable()
    {
        return enable;
    }

    public static String getName(int id)
    {
        if(isEnable())
            return "test";
        else
            return null;
    }

    public static ArrayList<String> getVars(int id, String str)
    {
        if(isEnable())
        {
            ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
            list.add("test1");
            list.add("test2");
            list.add("test3");
            return list;
        }

        return new ArrayList<String>();
    }

    //and more method contains enable check
}
```

how to check enable in single method and skip from all method

Comment: Do methods have to be all `static`?

Comment: yes all method is static

Comment: OK, not the best design, but I suppose you have your reasons to do it that way. If the class implemented an interface and methods were not static, then you could create a proxy for your class and intercept every method invocation to add your enabled/disabled logic there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you're using some funky aspect oriented library such as [AspectJ](https://eclipse.org/aspectj/) there's no way to automatically inject code before/after each method in a class.

You need to do it "manually" as you have shown in your example code.

Comment: Well, if the class implemented an interface and methods weren't static, then the OP could create a proxy that intercepted all methods and implemneted that logic enabled vs !enabled. But I think that would be too much hassle for such a simple thing as enabling/disabling.